# How to add a function when I unclick a button or a view?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I have multiple views that you can click, but the point is that when you click one of them the others can't be clicked, I tried this way:

1.Created a boolean variable that by default is false ( var isButtonClicked = false, or isViewClicked ),

2.Then when I click the button (or the view) (on onClickListener ) I make that variable true,

Now this works fine when I click one button (or the view) and the others can't be clicked, but the problem now is that I can't unclick the first button (view), and this is when I am stuck, I couldn't find anything about unClick in android.

Comment: could you please show the code that has all the button methods?

Comment: What is "unclick"? This behavior is unique to your app, Android won't know about it and how to manage your custom boolean field.

Comment: view1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
         @Override
         public void onClick() {
             if (!isButiionClicked){
             //implemented code
             isButtonClicked = false
            }
         }
    });
 I have 10 views more exactly,

Comment: Are you trying to toggle the boolean for every click you perform on the button?

Comment: yes , in every onClickMethod I set the boolean false , so I can't click the other buttons (views) @MichaelKrause

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking your word "unclick" to mean "clicked a second time".

Instead of using a Boolean, you can use a nullable View reference, kind of like this:

```
private var clickedButton: View? = null
lateinit val buttons: List<Button> // put the buttons in a list and assign to this in onCreate

// Set this listener on each button.
val buttonListener = OnClickListener { view ->
    when (view) {
        clickedButton -> {
            clickedButton = null
            // other things you want to do when toggling the button off
        }
        null -> {
            clickedButton = view
            // other things you want to do when toggling a button on
        }
        else -> {} // Do nothing. Some other button is toggled on.
    }
}
```

But it might be preferable to actually disable all the buttons that are not toggled on, so they visually look like you cannot press them. In that case, your listener should actively set the enabled state of all the buttons. Something like this:

```
private var isAButtonPressed = false
lateinit val buttons: List<Button> // put the buttons in a list and assign to this in onCreate

// Set this listener on each button.
val buttonListener = OnClickListener { view ->
    if (isAButtonPressed) {
        buttons.forEach { it.enabled = true }
        // other things you want to do when toggling a button off
    } else {
        buttons.forEach { it.enabled = it == view }
        // other things you want to do when toggling a button on
    }
    isAButtonPressed = !isAButtonPressed 
}
```

You might also consider using ToggleButton, which has checked and unchecked states.

Comment: Thanks this help to get the idea how to do it, because my situation is a little different